# Count number of obeserved Month in R

Tags: r, count

I have a data with `Date` as follows:

```
          2010-01-01
          2010-02-07
          2010-02-09
          2010-03-09
          2010-04-06
          ....
          2021-03-31
          2021-04-10
```

I want an output with number of observed `Month` based on `Date` as above such as: `1,2,3...100`
I tried this code `as.numeric(as.factor(format(flights.input$Date,"%m")))`
But it stops counting at `12`, and counts again from `1` while I want to count consecutively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
data.table::setDT(df)[, NumberOfMonth := rleid(format(as.Date(as.character(Date)), "%m"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

We. can use `rle` from `base R` to create the sequence after extracting the `month` from the 'Date' column

```
fm1 <- format(flights.input$Date, "%m")
with(rle(fm1), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
```

Comment: No, I want to count like: 1,2,3....,n not only 12 months per year. There might be more than one `Date` per Month

Comment: @JennyPham. It's not clear to me.  What would be the output after you get `fm1`

Comment: `fm1` is like: 1,2,...,12,1,2,3..,12. the output is the same to the code I tried `as.numeric(as.factor(format(flights.input$Date,"%m")))`

Comment: @JennyPham. If you have `1, 2, 3, .. 12, 1, 2, 3,.. 12` what is the expected

Comment: Literally, if there are 100 months. I need it counts up to 100. the answer of arg0naut91 is correct